# How to make a world only consists of one kind of block?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to have a world made of like stone or similar material and carve it out. How can I generate a world that only has stone?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Could you provide a bit more information? What version are you on, Legacy console or bedrock?

Comment: @Jayden Someone removed the "nintendo-switch" tag and then changed the "minecraft" tag wrong. He's on MCPE.

Answer (score 0):

There is no setting for that. You'll have to fly around and keep executing `/fill ~-15 ~-15 ~-15 ~15 ~15 ~15 stone replace dirt` and the same for all other blocks that could exist underground.